# jQuery function doesn't work after .load

Tags: jquery, fadeout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery events not happening after AJAX load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5878239/jquery-events-not-happening-after-ajax-load)

I've got function which re-load page after clicking a button, here it is:

```
$(".updated").load("index.php .updated");
```

It loads everything perfectly. But after loading other function which should fadeout table row - doesn't work. Here is the function:

```
$('.deletetable').click(function () {
 var x = this.id;
 $.post("Changes.php", { ID: x, CLEAR: '1'});
 $('#slideup'+x).fadeOut("slow");
```

It works fine aswell, but before .load happens.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: When you load new content, the old elements (the ones with the event bound) are lost. you need to either rebind them or use delegated events.

Comment: Note that .live is deprecated (that question is a year+ old) you should use `.on` or `.delegate`, read documentation for syntax differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.deletetable', function () {
    var x = this.id;
    $.post("Changes.php", {
        ID: x,
        CLEAR: '1'
    });
    $('#slideup' + x).fadeOut("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass your code as callback to load if you want it to executed after the load :

```
$(".updated").load("index.php .updated", function(){

    $('.deletetable').click(function () {
     var x = this.id;
     $.post("Changes.php", { ID: x, CLEAR: '1'});
     $('#slideup'+x).fadeOut("slow");
    })

});
```